# Storyboard build version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, storyboard, xcode6

I have changed the (Builds for) option to (iOS 8.0 and later).

[image: image 1]

this will make any side effects if I run the application on a device that has an older version ?

And what is the different between it and Deployment Target?
[image: image 2]

I do not understand this point so please try to explain it in details.
Thanks.

Comment: got any answers about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399497/builds-for-option-in-interface-builder   check this guy.